# How to use guilds.join?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have no idea how to use guilds.join. Are there any examples for this? On Github or something. i couldn't find it and i need help.‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏

‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏

‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏   ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏

Answer (score 0):

There's no such method as `guilds.join` in discord.js. Also I suppose this was meant to be a user method which is unpermitted by Discord itself please see the ToS and Guidelines (https://discordapp.com/guidelines and https://discordapp.com/terms)